# SQL inserting row into table invalid character

Tags: sql, oracle

```
        INSERT INTO MUSIC VALUES (12, 'WIZ KHALIFA', 'RAP', '8-SEPT-1987','NORTH DAKOTA');
        INSERT INTO MUSIC VALUES (13, 'EMINEM', 'RAP', '17-OCT-1972', 'MISSOURI');
        INSERT INTO MUSIC VALUES (14, 'NIGHT LOVELL', 'RAP', '29-MAY-1997', 'CANADA');
        INSERT INTO MUSIC VALUES (15, 'KEVIN GATES', 'RAP', '5-FEB-1986', 'LOUISIANA');
        INSERT INTO MUSIC VALUES (16, 'THE GAME', 'RAP', '29-NOV-1979', 'COMPTON');
```

Error is:

> ORA-00911: invalid character

Originally, it only had 3 columns: `ID`, `NAME`, and `GENRE`. Then I added two columns:

```
ADD artist_date_of_birth DATE;
ADD city_of_birth CHAR(50);
```

I'm using Oracle's iacademy thing.

Comment: On which particular query you get this error ? You also need to provide additional details like how your table is constructed

Comment: Very sorry, I'm new to SQL, the full error ORA-00911: invalid character and the table construct is ID, NAME, GENRE, DATE OF BIRTH, CITY OF BIRTH

Comment: I suspect it is the date values: They are all three letters except for `8-SEPT-1987`. Also, not all DB engines are created equal, some are better at handling string to date conversions.

Comment: From which query? Or all of them? What does your table look like

Comment: @Cory you need to edit your qusestion to include the information about your table and also specify the DBMS that you are using

Comment: I did ALTER TABLE MUSIC ADD city_of_creation CHAR(50); ADD artist_date_of_birth DATE;

Comment: Insert your date values as `TO_DATE('08-09-1987', 'DD-MM-YYYY')` or whichever format you prefer. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA

Comment: Only error I could recreate was using the default date format for 3 char month and you specifying SEPT in the first record.  Also, don't use CHAR type, use VARCHAR2 instead.  With CHAR(50), it will always store 50 bytes, but with VARCHAR2, it will only store based on the length of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I entered them one by one and didn't get an error... So confused.

Comment: Which tool do you use to run the statements? If you are using that dreaded browser frontend that comes with Oracle XE: that doesn't allow to run more then a single statement. Get a proper SQL client and ditch the browser based XE tool.